# Deploying Android app on Phone

Tags: android, android-studio, deploying

I have resently begun to develop Android apps, and I do not know how to deploy simple HelloWorld app on my Android device. When I click the **Run** button, my device ***is not shown*** in the list of running devices.

P.S.: I am using Android Studio.

Comment: did you enable the USB debugging option on your phone?

Comment: @Blackbelt Yes, I did.

Answer (score 0):

To change what your application defaults to when you click run or debug in Android Studio, go to **Run -> Edit Configurations....** Select the project and find the Target Device section under the General tab on the Android Application page. That seems to be where you toggle what the project builds to. If you're importing a project it actually defaults to Emulator, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable your developer settings on your device.
Once you’ve found the Build number section of the settings, tap on the section 7 times.

Stock Android: Settings > About phone > Build number

Samsung Galaxy S5: Settings > About device > Build number

LG G3: Settings > About phone > Software information > Build number

HTC One (M8): Settings > About > Software information > More > Build number

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install phone drivers on the PC/Mac before testing the apps on phone. It will show up in devices, once you install the drivers. If you have already installed the drivers of the phone, try reinstalling the drivers, for some reason this works on some devices. 
Also make sure you enable developer options and USB debugging.